# Who are all the people that Lawrence painted?

Tags: phineas-and-ferb

In the *Phineas and Ferb* season 1 episode “It's a Mud, Mud, Mud, Mud World”, Phineas and Ferb's dad Lawrence Fletcher paints a paint-by-numbers picture.  When he completes it, we see it together with six of his previous paintings, all portraits.

[image: Screencap of Lawrence's paintings]

Can you identify who all the paintings depict?  Are they supposed to be specific famous people?

I should add that Phineas later comments “Dad, you might want to wipe the queen off your face”, indicating that the painting that he just painted is a queen, possibly the queen of the U.K., where Lawrence grew up.

[image: Closeup on the painting of the queen, from an earlier screencap]

Comment: Bottom right is Winston Churchill

Comment: Upper-right looks like George H.W. Bush.  (a.k.a. Bush I)  The one he's handling might be Liz.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely Liz.  Curls, big clip-on earrings, pearls; not a great likeness but obviously her.  (Note that this is stretching the on-topicness a bit since this doesn't appear to be a science fictional aspect of the show per the tag guidelines...)

Comment: @DavidW The pearl necklace and big earrings don't distinguish her from queen Beatrix of the Netherlands, but the curly hair really looks more like queen Elizabeth II of the U.K.